# Electron App (for production) with any database in a single file

Tags: database, reactjs, electron

I'm begginer in **Electron ecosystem** and i need make one powerfull desktop app.

I choose the electron because i'm experient with JavaScript and i really want make one software using React xD.

I have many questions and the first of my list is:

*Can I put my "powerfull application" and the database (relational or not relational) in a single installer (for production) using the electron-builder?*

If it's possible, may you have some tutorials to share with me?

Thank you all.

Comment: Will every client have physical DB along with the application?

Comment: Yes, every client have a physical DB.

Comment: here is a tutorial https://stackabuse.com/nedb-a-lightweight-javascript-database/

Comment: I'll see the docs. Thanks!